# "Please enter alphanumeric characters" or "Please enter letters and numbers"?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

In form entries, what is most commonly understood?

"Please enter alphanumeric characters" or "Please enter letters and numbers"

Comment: I think this is probably more a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/ ; do you want me to migrate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about UX

Comment: I also think this should be migrated to UX